# What is the proper way to ask a question visible across multiple stackexchanges?

Tags: discussion, support

Suppose I have a question about Vim, such as the following [Is it possible to have separate visual mode in Split window vim when editing the same file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353021/is-it-possible-to-have-separate-visual-mode-in-split-window-vim-when-editing-the)

I have observed that there is a vim tag in StackOverflow, as well as in Programmers, and Unix. I think the question might be relevant to people in all three, but I do not think it is polite to triple-post.

What would be a reasonable way to spread the question to other stack exchanges where vim is relevant?

Comment: If questions about a special topic is on topic on more than one site, choose the site whether it is most easiest to get the answer. Since stackoverflow is one of the site, I would choose it hands down, since there is more people there than any other site..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Don't do it, it's painful**

We really don't want to start answering a question on a SE site just to see it was already answered elsewhere. It's better if we can collaborate to build one good answer rather than having parts of the answer made on different sites. A duplicate question brings nothing good.

**Don't do it, it's mostly useless**

Putting your question on SO or superuser already gives it a big audience. If what you want is to touch all people who are *really* interested in a given tag, then chances are that any site will do it because we have tools to be notified when a question appears in any site of the network, like email alerts or RSS feeds. So, simply choose the most relevant. And users are already looking at the sites holding the type of question they want to see and answer, no need to spam them elsewhere.

**Regarding your specific question**

In my opinion, this question should have been asked on [superuser](https://superuser.com/). There is no programming involved and it's only related to the use of the vim software. This doesn't mean it **must** be closed on SO, because as vim is commonly used for programming it might be seen as in our interest sphere but the most relevant SE site would have been superuser.

Answer (score 4):

**Please don't**.

Please read FAQs of the site before posting a question on it. I don't know anything about your question but IMHO any question is suitable only on one site. E.g. if your question is related to programming (code) ask it on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) etc...

Comment: The problem is that the vim editor is intimately related to coding, and has traditionally been a part of SO, but it is also intimately related to Unix and Programmers.

Comment: @merlin2011 - Vim tag is also available in [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vim) you may argue it is suitable there too.

Comment: @him056, That is my point exactly.

Comment: @merlin2011 - No. That is *my* point. Having a tag in XYZ site doesn't mean your question is always suitable there. You have to ask a question as per site's FAQ.